# jquery ui autocomplete Not filling the data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have jQuery UI autocomplete code as follows :

```
 $("#keyword").autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/formhandler/autocomplete",
                        data: {term: request.term, data: $("#city").val()},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            response($.map(response, function(item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item,
                                    value: item
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
```

and I have the response as json as follows :

```
 ["result1"]["reusult2"]["result3"]["result4"]["result4"]
```

How can I **autocomplete** the keyword field using this ?

Comment: The response should be a single array like this ["result1","reusult2","result3","result4"]

Comment: I got it , i was sending the json response without making it array :  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $details[] = $row->Keywords; } i didnt given  $details[]

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be using the parameter data of your ajax success function. Open the JavaScript console (F12 in chrome) and check if you get any error.

```
$("#keyword").autocomplete({
     source: function(request, response) {
     $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/formhandler/autocomplete",
       data: {term: request.term, data: $("#city").val()},
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
       //check what data contains. it should contain a string like "['val1','val2','val3','val4']"
       //the next line should use $.map(data and not $.map(response
       response($.map(response, function(item) {
         return {
           label: item,
           value: item
         }
    }));
 }
 })
}
});
```

Comment: data is like is as follows :  ["result1"]["reusult2"]["result3"]["result4"]["result4"]

Comment: is should be  ["result1", "reusult2", "result3", "result4", "result4"]

Comment: yeah i have to make  ["result1"]["reusult2"]["result3"]["result4"]["result4"] in to this  ["result1", "reusult2", "result3", "result4", "result4"] through jquery i think ,do you have any idea

Comment: data = data.replace(/\\]\\[/g,",");

Comment: TypeError: data.replace is not a function
 data = data.replace(/\]\[/g,",");

Comment: You need to find what data is -Try a debugger and check. First convert the response to a JavaScript array and then call $.map. To convert a string to an array use eval(data.replace(/\\]\\[/g,","))

Comment: Its not a string i think , i cant do that replace function

Comment: response is this : function ( content ) {
   if ( index === requestIndex ) {
    that.__response( content );
   }

   that.pending--;
   if ( !that.pending ) {
    that.element.removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
   }
  }

Comment: WOW it worked i didnt given this :  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $details[] = $row->Keywords; } in php.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using $.ajax. You can just get the data from $.get as a source.

```
$("#keyword").autocomplete({
              source : function (request, response) {
              $.get("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/formhandler/autocomplete", {term: request.term, data: $("#city").val()}, function (data) {
                response(data);
            });
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine these  arrays> Use :

```
$.merge
```

You may have to use a loop. A example can be this :

```
var first = ['a','b','c'];
var second = ['d','e','f'];
$.merge( $.merge([],first), second);
```

Which would output :

```
["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```